# Using common partition on dual system - Win10 + Ubuntu20.04 with common HOME folders

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, shared-folders

I have a laptop with only one ssd slot, so space is precious. I bought 2TB ssd and am running dual boot Win10 + Ubuntu 20.04 - using more KDE Plasma then Gnome. I have two small partitions one for each of the systems and rest of the disk for all the shared data. Originally formatted as NTFS I could not make it work properly in linux and being told that Linux does not work that well with NTFS, I decided to use ExFat. The aim was to have a shared folders for Documents, Pictures and Music, as I am synchronizing them with my Qnap NAS and it is a pain to have two sets of these folders for each system. Trying to move these folders from HOME to the ExFat partition, I actually run into a problem with permissions. I have run `sudo mv $HOME/Music/mnt/AFD6-C938/Music` so I could symlink the folder back and I got: `mv: failed to preserve ownership for '/mnt/AFD6-C938/Music': Operation not permitted I have read now, that Fat system can not work with permission.` Is there any workaround? Is there any other way, how to achieve my goal? Could anyone help here? I am lost... I have set up permission for the whole partition to 0777 and still the same... Cheers!

```bsh
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=a0b9825b-8a77-47b3-9751-e3bda8a20a6b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=0C80-675A  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/554EC1F141ADD65B /mnt/554EC1F141ADD65B auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Seagate_BUP_BL_NA7PYSG0-0:0-part2 /mnt/usb-Seagate_BUP_BL_NA7PYSG0-0:0-part2 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-WD_My_Passport_25AF_575838314442374552353856-0:0-part2 /mnt/usb-WD_My_Passport_25AF_575838314442374552353856-0:0-part2 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/AFD6-C938 /mnt/AFD6-C938 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HONzP.png]

[image: fstab]

Comment: I recommend formatting the common partition as **ext4** which is greatly compatible with linux (and also has much less fragmentation) and also you can [access linux filesystems in windows with third-party softwares](https://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/).

Comment: Thanks for your message, but I need full read-write-execute support in Windows, but from what I have read, it is not a save option. If things have developed further and it is not so any longer, please point me to some prove of it and I am happy to do it.

Comment: Please edit your post and add the present partition layout and also your `/etc/fstab`

Comment: I have tried to edit the post, but it created some mess in it... not easy interface. The link in the beginning points to .png screen shot of my partition layout and the text at the end is the content of my fstab... sorry for that!

Comment: if you edit the post and before the content of fstab have an empty line and then preceed every line from fstab with 4 blanks, it will appear as it should. I could edit it but I don't know exactly how to break the lines

Comment: please see the link at the end - taking screenshot looks more efficient, if it's OK for your purpose...

Comment: Use code formatting to show configuration files, please: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Thanks a lot, it will require a bit more time and it is a bed time here, in Australia. I will be back here tomorrow, if you cold kindly help...

Comment: The normal scenario in a dual-boot setup, is to leave Windows and Ubuntu in their native formats (NTFS and ext4), and to create another NTFS partition to share data files.

Comment: Could you make another edit with the output from `blkid`, then I can compile a good `/etc/fstab` and put it as an edit in my answer. And how is the WD My Passport connected?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who participated and especially for cleaning my post from the terrible typo... :) I think it was my first post here, and I had not studied how to do it properly beforehand; focused on my problem only...

Comment: With using of NTFS - that's exactly, how I had it configured before. Without the changes in fstab. It looked nice and neat solution to me, but then I run in problems with certain SW, which would only use the system folders; SW which I am using from both operating systems, like DaVinci Resolve, or Vivaldi browser, which still does not sync the sessions. The problem is, I just have to use Windows sometimes for some specific tasks. So I attempted to use the shared partition to fix this, but have run into these linux permissions problems. Do I have any other solutions?

Comment: The /dev/nvme0n1p7 is holding another linux distro, I am going to erase. That 'MyPassport' drive is and usb connected a backup drive, will don't stay there. The Qnap NAS address is 192.168.1.2 and how can I get the 'blkid' output, please?

Comment: With Ubuntu up and running, open a terminal window and issue the command `blkid`, Paste the result in an edit to your post. Our biggest problem is time. We live on opposite ends of the world. There are several ways to solve your problem but the easiest is what I sketched in my answer below. It will be more spcific once I get the `blkid` output.

Comment: It is quiet here, so I will try one more thing - btrfs, which now has got an opensource driver for Windows. Will let you all know, how it worked within few days... fingers crossed!

Comment: OK, but I still would like to see the output from `sudo blkid`, and also the name of the folder on your QNAP NAS

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it, based on what you have already done.

1. change the exfat partition to NTFS (backup all data first)
2. use `blkid` to find UUID for all partitions and change the rules
   in `/etc/fstab` to look something like this (it is my `fstab` with
   fictious UUIDs)

   ```
   # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
   #
   # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
   # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
   # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
   #
   # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
   # / was on /dev/sda4 during installation
   UUID=b75cccbc-b593-11ea-8460-474c3ce68281 /               ext4     errors=remount-ro 0       1

   # /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
   UUID=00DA-76C2  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1

   # /home was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
   UUID=ba8e2b4c-b593-11ea-9e46-73bf5d306e99 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2

   # /opt was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
   UUID=bb971558-b593-11ea-b501-8b6ce84c818b /opt            ext4    defaults        0       2

   # swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
   UUID=bc530f7e-b593-11ea-9af6-f3b4407e7176 none            swap    sw              0       0

   # Access to public volume on Synology NAS
   192.168.1.2:/volume1/public /mnt/public nfs _netdev,noauto,x-systemd.automount,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr 0  0

   # Access to backup volume on Synology NAS
   192.168.1.2:/volume1/backup /mnt/backup nfs _netdev,noauto,x-systemd.automount,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr 0  0

   # Access to work volume on Synology NAS
   192.168.1.2:/volume2/work /mnt/work nfs _netdev,noauto,x-systemd.automount,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr 0  0

   # read-only storage connected to Router USB
   //192.168.1.1/router-storage /mnt/router cifs guest,vers=1.0 0  0

   ### Mount the common NTFS partition read/write for user 1000 read-only for group 1000
   UUID=6981987E4DD51192 /mnt/win ntfs-3g   defaults,nls=utf8,umask=027,dmask=027,fmask=137,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names 0 0
   ```
3. Mount the common partition as `D:` in windows.
4. Put the common folders in that partition and link to them from your
   user account in windows (`C:\Users\...`). In Linux you just open
   them as usual.
5. Access for NFS in QNAP server is to be set as 192.168.1.0/24, but I am not
   aware of the permission settings in QNAP.